# How do I Integrate MDBootstrap in Ionic3+?

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, angular5, mdbootstrap

I had implemented an application in Angular5 with MDBootstrap which
provides rich UI, MDBootstrap successfully works in it.

Now my question is **How to integrate MDBootstrap in my Ionic
Project**, I tried a lot but can't get a successful result.

Comment: We didn't check the integration with Ionic 3, so I can't give you any ready answers on how to integrate Ionic applications with MDB Angular.

In the future, if you have any further questions about MDBootstrap, please use our [official support](https://mdbootstrap.com/support).

Comment: did you ever get this to work?